# What is the purpose /name of this CMOS gate configuration?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

I have tried search via google images, but it's not good at recognizing line drawings

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawn as logic instead of transistors, it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faXERNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bottom branch is A & !B & C, the top branch is !A & B & !C, so the final expression is

$$OUT = A \overline{B} C + \overline{A} B \overline{C}$$

It isn't clear why this was implemented as multiplexers rather than a more conventional SOP circuit.

Comment: I didn't make the circuit. Just curious about it.